# Factor to date conversion produces NA

Tags: r, type-conversion, data-conversion

I'm working on a kaggle dataset and here's some sample code:

Before:

```
Date  Open  High   Low Close   Volume Adj.Close
1 6/29/2010 19.00 25.00 17.54 23.89 18766300     23.89
2 6/30/2010 25.79 30.42 23.30 23.83 17187100     23.83
3  7/1/2010 25.00 25.92 20.27 21.96  8218800     21.96
4  7/2/2010 23.00 23.10 18.71 19.20  5139800     19.20
5  7/6/2010 20.00 20.00 15.83 16.11  6866900     16.11
6  7/7/2010 16.40 16.63 14.98 15.80  6921700     15.80
```

Now here's the class of each column from left to right (factor, numeric, numeric, numeric, numeric, integer, numeric)

I applied this line of code to change my date(factor) column to a date type

```
data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

now when I did that I ran "sapply(data, class)" again and a  "is.factor(data$Date)" to check and it worked! 
But here's the problem:

```
Date  Open  High   Low Close   Volume Adj.Close
1       <NA> 19.00 25.00 17.54 23.89 18766300     23.89
2       <NA> 25.79 30.42 23.30 23.83 17187100     23.83
3 2010-01-07 25.00 25.92 20.27 21.96  8218800     21.96
4 2010-02-07 23.00 23.10 18.71 19.20  5139800     19.20
5 2010-06-07 20.00 20.00 15.83 16.11  6866900     16.11
6 2010-07-07 16.40 16.63 14.98 15.80  6921700     15.80
```

My dataset 1692x7 and I did an NA count and now I got 1021 NA's (60% of the data)

Anyone know a better method converting factors to date types without all the NA's?

Comment: I don't understand how this question is considered off-topic by the r-comm or the question cannot be reproduced when a head view of the dataset is displayed twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `as.Date(df$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")` instead of `as.Date(data$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")`.

```
as.Date(df$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
# [1] "2010-06-29" "2010-06-30" "2010-07-01" "2010-07-02" "2010-07-06"
# [6] "2010-07-07"
```

It's `month/day/year` not `day/month/year`

Comment: thank you! the code works, I really wanted to keep the dd/mm/yyyy format, but i'll manage!